# Return a list containing the number with most repeats from a list of numbers

Tags: python, list, count

Assuming input:

```
a = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5]
```

Expected output:

```
[1,5]
```

As there are 4 fours and 4 fives, they are both the number with the most repeats. Hence I put them into a new list.

My code:

```
a.count(1) --> result1 = 4
a.count(5) --> result2 = 4
...  --> for rest of the value in a
[1, 5]
```

However, this is like hardcoding, is there any suggestion on how to do this effectively? Thanks!!!

Comment: @devnull Hi, I check the page that you mention, I think the difference is that inside the list they return tuples with the element and the number of repeats as elements, while I just need the number. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

super inefficient one-liner

```
>>> a = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5]
>>> [x for x in set(a) if a.count(x) == max(map(a.count, a))]
[1, 5]
```

You can make it reasonably efficient like this

```
>>> (lambda mx=max(map(a.count, set(a))): [x for x in set(a) if a.count(x) == mx])()
[1, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

```
>>> a
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
>>> unique=set(a)
>>> unique
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> MAX=0
>>> for i in unique:
        if a.count(i)>MAX:
           MAX=a.count(i)
>>> set([i for i in a if a.count(i)==MAX])
set([1, 5])
```

Comment: You are hardcoding `4`. That is what exactly he is trying to avoid.